# How do I re-use code in Java in this structure?

Tags: java

In simple words... imagine I have a class like this:

```
@Path("/someUniquePath")
public class AuthorizePerson
{
   @GET
   public Response authorizeMeGetRequest(... any # of parameters)
   {
     return authorize(... any # of parameters);
   }

   public Response authorize()
   {
     // check if I'm a human

     // check if I have roles A, B, then C

     return Response.ok().build();
   }
}
```

Now say I have another resource:

```
@Path("/someUniquePath")
public class AuthorizeSpecificPerson extends AuthorizePerson
{
   @GET
   public Response authorizeMeGetRequest(... any # of parameters)
   {
     // Do something

     // if I'm 6 ft tall
     return authorizeTallPerson();

     // else
     return authorize();
   }

   public Response authorizeTallPerson()
   {
     // check if I'm a human

     // check if I have roles A

     // use role A to determine if I'm a tall person

     // check for roles B, C

     return Response.ok().build();
   }
```

Now to handle re-using code, I was thinking to have another class that can provide me with the methods that I can call as needed, I'm taking the composition approach.

but then my method becomes

```
public Response authorizeTallPerson()
   {
     myClass.checkIfHuman();

     myClass.checkIfRoleA();

     myClass.checkIfTallPerson();

     myClass.checkIfRoleBAndC();

     return Response.ok().build();
   }
```

And my base class becomes:

```
public Response authorize()
   {
     myClass.checkIfHuman();

     myClass.checkIfRoleA();

     myClass.checkIfRoleBAndC();

     return Response.ok().build();
   }
```

Notice there is still patterns. Both need to check if the person is a human and if they have role A. It seems like I'm just re-using code re-use... like its becoming nested. I hope this makes sense... how can I handle this?

It's not as simple as having a common method that performs both tasks:

```
public Response checkCommon()
{
  myClass.checkIfHuman();
  myClass.checkRoleA();
  return Response.ok().build();
}
```

because then my callers need to make conditional decisions... if the user is not human, `authorize` method needs to return a different type of Response etc.

Comment: Use java filters

Comment: What about creating a class for authorization and a subclass for tall person authorization?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you have two authentication flows? This pretty much sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why is there a separate flow for tall people? Are tall people allowed or not? What does it depends on? If it's just by path (AuthorizePerson doesn't care about height, AuthorizeSpecificPerson does) then have the AuthorizeSpecificPerson do the tall people checks as part of authorize() itself, preferably using super() for common parts. Which would be easier if these methods returned booleans or something instead of Response.

Comment: @Deltharis I think id be violating OOP principles by doing that. Base class doesn't need to care or know about those details that only AuthorizeSpecificPerson cares about

Comment: This is typically done with _aspect-oriented programming_, such as with Spring Security's `@PreAuthorize`.

Comment: Uh... No, Base class doesn't need to know what child does. But child can know and extend and change to fit the context what parent does, that's exactly the purpose of having a child class with overriden methods in the first place. So have an overriden authorize() method in child. Let it use parent authorize() if it makes sense (and in the given example it does - parent checks everything except tall person stuff), or write it from scratch. And use the well defined authorize method when using this class family. You do not want to debug cases where you used wrong authorize method.